# "Resource not found" exception while trying to load resource in NotepadV1 sample exercice

Tags: android, exception, resources

I am new to Android (but not to Java), I follow sample exercice NotepadV1 but I get a strange error while executing on virtual device (Hello World worked fine on this same vd):

I get a "Resource not found" exception when running the program. The used ID is correct (Eclipse show it to me as an autocompletion proposal, and it's well defined in R.java).
If I use directly the string instead of the resource ID, all things are good.

Here is my string.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string
        name="app_name">Notepad v1</string>
    <string
        name="no_notes">No Notes Yet</string>
    <string
        name="menu_insert">Add Item</string>
</resources>
```

And here is the function where the exception is thrown:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu( Menu menu )
{
    boolean result = super.onCreateOptionsMenu( menu );
    // menu.add( 0, INSERT_ID, 0, R.string.menu_insert ); // exception !
    menu.add( 0, INSERT_ID, 0, "Add Item" ); // ok like this
    return result;
}
```

The commented out line is the one which throws exception. As you see, when giving directly the string instead of resource ID, it pass.
I've tried to load this resource elsewhere in the same program, and the exception is thrown everywhere. Other resources are used on other places in the program, without problem.

Anybody have an idea ? Did I missed something ?

Thanks a lot for your ideas

Comment: random suggestion: have you tried to clean the project (Project -> Clean... in Eclipse)

Comment: Just a check: is your string.xml in a /res/values/ directory?

Comment: this is a warning correct? "Resources don't contain package" in logcat?

Comment: @user you should probably make the "Clean" suggestion into an answer and accept it.

Comment: bumped into this, found Peter's answer spot on. I have a partner developing the strings.xml for the app, so when i replace i missed some strings. Strange eclipse did'nt manage to catch it and application kept crashing with the message "resource not found" - thanks Peter, i would be knee deep trying to figure out which resource if not for your hint :)

Comment: @Gautier: Thanks, it works for me. What a strange problem! :(

Comment: If I am creating the LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this); ll.setId(int);. If I am getting this id by ll.getId(). I am facing the error, "Resource Id not found". How can I resolve this issue.?

Answer (score 34):

I have had the same issue and cleaning the Project in Eclipse solved it.

Comment: Same here. Although it does not happen everytime I add a resource (layout, string, etc). But sometimes it does. Cleaning the project always helps. Why does this happen though, as the generated java file is correct? Maybe the APK packaging is buggy?

Answer (score 1):

Very strange, but I was able to get this to work by referencing the string as `getResources().getString(R.string.menu_insert)`

and by reordering the string constants in the R.java file. `no_notes` had a higher value than `menu_insert`, but was listed ahead of `menu_insert`.  So I listed them in order of numeric constant, and it worked:

```
public static final class string {
    public static final int app_name=0x7f040000;
    public static final int menu_insert=0x7f040001;
    public static final int no_notes=0x7f040002;
}
```

Accessing the string through `getResources().getString()` usually is sufficient, so this must be some bug in Eclipse or the sdk.

Comment: My understanding is that you should never modify the `R.java` file?

Comment: "Never say never." You shouldn't make it a common activity, and not including this time, I've probably done it once. So it's on rare occasions.

Comment: Fair enough. Follow-up Q: How do you prevent the system from undoing your change (assuming the problem persists) after a clean/rebuild, since eclipse (what I've been using) always regenerates this file?

Answer (score 0):

Adding it manually to the strings.xml instead of using the "Resources" tab helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `R` file from the `gen` Eclipse folder. It will then be regenerated and the problem hopefully resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I think:

Resource:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>   
<resources>   
    <string name="exEditTextEmpty">Program could not get access to EditText view</string>
</resources>
```

Code:

```
Exception ex = new Exception(getResources().getString(R.string.exEditTextEmpy));
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when I renamed (with refactor) a project. Clean didn't help, but Eclipse restart do help.