# Show progress of seekbar in a textview inside a custom alert dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have a custom alert dialog which contains a seekbar and a textview. I want to display progress of seekbar in that textview in percents when the user interacts with the thumb of seekbar..

here is my code..

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(PrefsActivity.this);
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View layoutFromInflater = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_fragment_sensitivity_layout, null);      
builder.setView(layoutFromInflater)
    .setPositiveButton("Ok", new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
    }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });


    final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();

    TextView progress_tv = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.seekbar_progress_tv2);           
    progress_tv.setText("sdf"); 
    SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) dialog.findViewById(R.id.seekBar1); 
    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) { 
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,boolean fromUser) {                             
            System.out.println("progress... " + progress);      
            progress_tv.setText(progress);  // Exception...
        }
    });
```

unfortunately, whenever i try to drag the thumb , the application crashes giving me an

ResourceNotFound exception inside onSeekBarChangeListener where i set the progress of seekbar to that textview.

I've already tried both..

```
TextView progress_tv = (TextView) dialog
                .findViewById(R.id.seekbar_progress_tv2);
```

and

```
TextView progress_tv = (TextView) layoutFromInflater
                    .findViewById(R.id.seekbar_progress_tv2);
```

but still problem persist..

Any help is appreciated..

Comment: Did you try project->clean as suggested here http://stackoverflow.com/q/5212747/603744

Comment: i did.. infact several times.. i even closed-reopened project. closed - restarted eclipse but still its giving the same exception..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TextView` expects to get `charSequence` and you pass an int to it. One way to solve this is `Integer.toString(progress)`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting null as parent add your root layout as parent while inflating the dialog layout as below.

```
View layoutFromInflater = inflater
                           .inflate(R.layout.dialog_fragment_sensitivity_layout,
                           (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.yourLayoutRoot));
```

and find the views by `layoutFromInflater` only.

Hope this should work fine for you.

Comment: have a reference at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184104/how-do-i-put-a-seek-bar-in-an-alert-dialog

Comment: i referred that post and i think my implementation of alertdialog is almost similar to the one given in accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

```
Dialog yourDialog = new Dialog(this);
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_dialog,(ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.your_dialog_root_element));
yourDialog.setContentView(layout);
```

Thus, you can operate on your element as follows:

```
TextView yourDialogTextView = (TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.your_dialog_tv);
SeekBar yourDialogSeekBar = (SeekBar)layout.findViewById(R.id.your_dialog_seekbar);
// ...
```

and so on, to set listeners for seekbar.

EDIT: The seekbar onchangelistener should be as follows:

```
OnSeekBarChangeListener yourSeekBarListener = new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        //add code here
}

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        //add code here
}

@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBark, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        //add code here
yourDialogTextView.setText(progress);
    }
 };
 yourDialogSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(yourSeekBarListener);
```

Comment: i already tried using a custom dialog instead using a custom alert dialog but it doesnt help either..

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a pretty old question but it's actually really easy. Just type this

```
progress_tv.setText("" + progress + "%");
```